# installing interactive ruby shell on windows

Tags: irb

I'm facing, when trying to load irb after ruby installation

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module:RbReadline                                                                                                    >': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point                                                                                                     to a directory (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rbreadline.rb:17:in `<top (r                                                                                                    equired)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:10:in `<module:R                                                                                                    eadline>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/readline.rb:8:in `<top (requ                                                                                                    ired)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/input-method.rb:129:in `<module:IR                                                                                                    B>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb/input-method.rb:14:in `<top (requi                                                                                                    red)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/irb.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54                                                                                                    :in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:9:in `<main>'
```

how should i point HOME var.
I've been trying to run irb from my c:\Ruby22-x75\bin> still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Went to search-> environment changes -> goes menu system prorerties ->environment vars changes and added HOME with a path of my \bin on installed ruby directory